# Handling Errors (i.e. Content Length) Within an HttpHandler

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm working on an uploader built with an HttpHandler.  I would like to create a routine to handle all uncaught errors including content length error.

```
<%@ webhandler class="MyNamespace.UploadHandler" %>

Namespace MyNamespace

Class UploadHandler

  Implements IHttpHandler

  ReadOnly Property IsReusable As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
      Return False
    End Get
  End Property

  Sub Page_Error(sender As Object,e As EventArgs)

    ' Never fires

  End Sub

  Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

  ...

  End Sub

End Class

End Namespace
```

It's critical that I handle any 404.13 (request exceeds request content length) error in the httphandler itself.

I would also like Page_Error to handle any uncaught exceptions but it never fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this just cannot be done.  From scouring the net, it seems that the only possible place to catch the 404.13 error is in Application_BeginRequest.  I don't think that's going to work for my purposes but maybe it will help someone else.  I'll be handling the error from the JavaScript side.

As to Page_Error - that's not part of HttpHandler so the only solution is a try/catch block around the work done in ProcessRequest.